# How to stop Azure Worker Role

Tags: multithreading, azure

We have 1-2 worker,which spins 5 threads, each thread read messages from Azure queue and do long processing, each processing may take around 1-2 hrs. We would like to implement logic to Stop particular thread at particular worker role. User will submit request to cancel particular processing. We are saving worker role and thread information in our azure table. But we are stuck in implementing to stop particular worker role's thread which is processing. can any one give some idea/design to stop particular thread in particular worker. Can we make use of cancellation token of thread to stop thread. Please help us in stopping worker role's thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a flag of some sort. So either a new queue which is monitored or a DB update.

Then have a new thread started in your worker role that monitors for these cancellation messages/flags, picks the right thread and stops it.

I wouldn't recommend doing anything within the thread that is processing because it would slow down your work, however if your thread has an OnStop method, you can use that to tidy up the thread before shutting it down.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Your approach gives me directions. however i havent understand abt "if your thread has an OnStop method, you can use that to tidy up the thread before shutting it down." r u speaking abt within thread cancellation ?  ... My Another question is in case if we have 2 worker roles how can Worker Role's thread can be shutdown. Your approach works perfect If it is same worker role.

Comment: On each worker role you will need to start the threads. Keep a reference to these threads. I have done this previously by using a List<Thread> to keep them. Outside of this thread have another thread running to monitor the flags in the DB. Once it detects a flag to stop the thread you can call a Thread.Abort();

Comment: Thanks Adam. Let me try